# OpenGL ES 2.0 Texture loading visual glitch

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I have been successful in rendering primitives with a colour component via the shader and also translating them. However, upon attempting to load a texture and render it for the primitive via the shader, the primitives glitch, they should be squares:

[image]

As you can see, it successfully loads and applies the texture with the colour component to the single primitive in the scene.

If I then remove the color component, I again have primitives, but oddly, they are scaled by changing the uvs -  this should not be the case, only the uvs should scale! (also their origin is offset)

My shader init code:

```
   void renderer::initRendererGfx()
 {
shader->compilerShaders();

shader->loadAttribute(@"Position");
shader->loadAttribute(@"SourceColor");
shader->loadAttribute(@"TexCoordIn");

 }
```

Here is my object handler rendering function code:

```
void renderer::drawRender(glm::mat4 &view, glm::mat4 &projection)
   {
  //Loop through all objects of base type OBJECT
for(int i=0;i<SceneObjects.size();i++){
    if(SceneObjects.size()>0){
        shader->bind();//Bind the shader for the rendering of this object
        SceneObjects[i]->mv = view * SceneObjects[i]->model;
        shader->setUniform(@"modelViewMatrix", SceneObjects[i]->mv);//Calculate object model view
        shader->setUniform(@"MVP", projection * SceneObjects[i]->mv);//apply projection transforms to object


        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); // unneccc in practice
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, SceneObjects[i]->_texture);

        shader->setUniform(@"Texture", 0);//Apply the uniform for this instance
        SceneObjects[i]->draw();//Draw this object
        shader->unbind();//Release the shader for the next object
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my sprite buffer initialisation and draw code:

```
 void spriteObject::draw()
{
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(SpriteVertex), NULL);

glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(SpriteVertex) , (GLvoid*)     (sizeof(GL_FLOAT) * 3));
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(SpriteVertex) , (GLvoid*)(sizeof(GL_FLOAT) * 7));

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(SpriteIndices)/sizeof(SpriteIndices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

}
 void spriteObject::initBuffers()
{
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(SpriteVertices), SpriteVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(SpriteIndices), SpriteIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

  }
```

Here is the vertex shader:

```
 attribute vec3 Position;
 attribute vec4 SourceColor;

 varying vec4 DestinationColor;

 uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
 uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
 uniform mat4 MVP;

 attribute vec2 TexCoordIn;
 varying vec2 TexCoordOut;

 void main(void) {
 DestinationColor = SourceColor;
 gl_Position = MVP * vec4(Position,1.0);
 TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn;
  }
```

And finally the fragment shader:

```
  varying lowp vec4 DestinationColor;

  varying lowp vec2 TexCoordOut;
  uniform sampler2D Texture;

  void main(void) {
  gl_FragColor = DestinationColor * texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);
  }
```

If you want to see any more specifics of certain elements, just ask.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your triangles have the same winding? The winding is the order in which the triangle points are listed ( either clockwise or counter-clockwise ). The winding is used in face culling to determine if the triangle is facing or back-facing.

You can easily check if your triangle are wrongly winded by disabling face culling.

```
glDisable( GL_CULL_FACE );
```

More information here ( http://db-in.com/blog/2011/02/all-about-opengl-es-2-x-part-23/#face_culling )

Comment: I did glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE), nothing happened. But glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE) and I get an obscure glitch again

Comment: I have also discovered, if I make changes to the colour component in my vertex structure, it changes the primitive geometry. Is it possible they are getting mixed up?

Comment: Can you add the SpriteVertices definition?